# Install C++ json boost on RHEL machine

Tags: linux, c++11, boost, rhel, boost-json

I am trying to install json boost (boost_json) library on my linux RHEL machine.
I got the latest tar file from boost.org i.e. boost_1_83_0.tar.gz. After untaring the file I ran the following commands.

> ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=json  --prefix=/usr/local

> sudo ./b2 install

I running the above commands, I did not face any error but boost_json library did not get installed.
Requesting you to kindly assist me with installing the boost_json library

Note : I even tried to install boost library  with yum but no change

> sudo yum install boost boost-devel

Also, I can use the following line and skip the installation but I want to try with the installed library

> #include <boost/json/src.hpp>

Comment: can you verify if the Boost JSON library is installed on your RHEL system " find /usr/lib /usr/local/lib -name '*boost_json*' "

Comment: @CY5 : Checked in mentioned directories but 'boost_json' library not found

Comment: i see you cmd sudo yum install boost-devel has some typo can you fix it and reinstall it again. it got additional boost keyword in it.

Comment: @CY5 : Tried with correct sudo cmd but still the same issue.

Comment: check any dep missing or you can check /var/log/yum.log.  paste boost installation related error in the log path in your above question will be helpful to dig in.

Comment: @CY5 : Was unable to identify the issue from logs. Later, tried to install boost_json on RHEL 9.2 and it worked without any issues. Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading the OS to RHEL 9.2, the issue got resolved.